# Displaying totals in the ListView LayoutTemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview

I'm using the ListView control (ASP.NET 2008) to show a bunch of lines of data, and at the bottom I want some totals. I was initially going to define the header and footer in the LayoutTemplate and get the totals with some local function, i.e. <%#GetTheSum()%>, but it appears that the LayoutTemplate does not process the <%#...%> syntax.

Another thought would be to put a Label in the LayoutTemplate and use FindControl to update it. Not sure if that's possible (will try shortly).

What's the best way to show totals using a ListView?

UPDATE: Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212048/displaying-totals-in-the-listview-layouttemplate#212308).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that FindControl does work:

```
CType(MyListView.FindControl("litTotal"), Literal).Text = GetTheSum()
```

I'd still like to know if there might be a better way though.

Comment: in ASP.NET web forms (non-MVC), that's the way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a literal and set the variable in the code-behind.

```
<asp:Literal ID="litTotal" runat="server" />
```

code-behind:

```
litTotal.Text = GetTheSum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the control in the code-behind because it's in the LayoutTemplate. Maybe with FindControl, but I haven't tried that yet.